# Simple expression with boost::spirit

Tags: c++, parsing, boost-spirit, boost-phoenix

I need to parse `simple_expression ::= limit int_number (days | hours | minutes)`. I wrote code for grammar

```
struct Parser: grammar<std::string::const_iterator, boost::spirit::ascii::space_type>
{
public:
  Parser(ConditionTree& a_lTree):
    Parser::base_type(limit_expression),
    m_lTree(a_lTree)
  {
    using boost::spirit::qi::uint_;

    using boost::spirit::qi::_1;
    using boost::spirit::qi::_2;

    limit_expression = limit_days_operator | limit_hours_operator | limit_minutes_operator ;

    limit_days_operator = ( string("limit") > uint_ > string("days") )[ phoenix::bind( &ConditionTree::AddDaysLimitOperator, m_lTree, _2) ]  ;
    limit_hours_operator = ( string("limit") > uint_ > string("hours") )[ phoenix::bind( &ConditionTree::AddHoursLimitOperator, m_lTree, _2) ]  ;
    limit_minutes_operator = ( string("limit") > uint_ > string("minutes") )[ phoenix::bind( &ConditionTree::AddMinutesLimitOperator, m_lTree, _2) ] ;

    BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(limit_expression);

    BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(limit_days_operator);
    BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(limit_hours_operator);
    BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(limit_minutes_operator);
  }

  rule<std::string::const_iterator, boost::spirit::ascii::space_type> limit_expression;
  rule<std::string::const_iterator, boost::spirit::ascii::space_type> limit_days_operator;
  rule<std::string::const_iterator, boost::spirit::ascii::space_type> limit_hours_operator;
  rule<std::string::const_iterator, boost::spirit::ascii::space_type> limit_minutes_operator;

  ConditionTree& m_lTree;
}


void main()
{

  ConditionTree oTree;

  Parser parser(oTree);

  std::string strTest("limit5minutes");

  std::string::const_iterator it_begin(strTest.begin());
  std::string::const_iterator it_end(strTest.end());

  bool result = phrase_parse(it_begin, it_end, parser, space);
}
```

But it can't compile with following 2 errors:
`/usr/include/boost/spirit/home/support/argument.hpp:103: ошибка: no matching function for call to 'assertion_failed(mpl_::failed************ (boost::spirit::result_of::get_arg<boost::fusion::vector1<unsigned int&>, 1>::index_is_out_of_bounds::************)())'`

`/usr/include/boost/spirit/home/phoenix/bind/detail/member_function_ptr.hpp:103: ошибка: invalid initialization of reference of type 'const unsigned int&' from expression of type 'mpl_::void_'`

on line 
`limit_days_operator = ( string("limit") > uint_ > string("days") )[ phoenix::bind( &ConditionTree::AddDaysLimitOperator, m_lTree, _2) ]  ;`

I tryed to move semantic action to uint_ :

```
limit_days_operator = string("limit") > uint_ [ phoenix::bind( &ConditionTree::AddDaysLimitOperator, m_lTree, _1) ] > string("days")  ;
limit_hours_operator = string("limit") > uint_ [ phoenix::bind( &ConditionTree::AddHoursLimitOperator, m_lTree, _1) ] > string("hours")  ;
```

Then the parser correctly read `limit5days`, but not correctly `limit5minutes`, because, as I see, it can't differ `limit5days` from `limit5hours`.

Comment: `void main()`, seriously? (You must be using a compiler from the 1990s to compile this)

Answer (score 3):

There's a lot going on here. However, by the time I was done fixing up little things trying to read it and make it complete (SSCCE), it compiled too: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a510cfe7ffe45fee)**

I briefly illuminate some individual points here:

- the bind expressions in the semantic action copy `m_lTree` by value, this way you can't mutate the member. `phx::ref` was required here
- the expectation points made it impossible to parse anything other than *"days"* limits successfully
- use `lit` unless you actually want to consume the value of the string as an attribute. Better yet, just write `"limit" >> uint_ >> "days"` because overload overloading does the rest

As you've noticed there are number of anti-patterns in this grammar, making it complex:

- [Boost Spirit: "Semantic actions are evil"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8259440/boost-spirit-semantic-actions-are-evil)
- the **[reference-type member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841299/copying-a-c-class-with-a-member-variable-of-reference-type)** `m_lTree` leads to [Action At A Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_at_a_distance) and tight coupling.

## However:

That all said, I'd simplify things by **[avoiding semantic actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8259440/boost-spirit-semantic-actions-are-evil)**, and separating parsing and evaluation. 
Simply parsing into a `Limit` struct:

```
qi::rule<Iterator, ConditionTree::Limit(), Skipper> limit_expression;

limit_expression = "limit" >> qi::uint_ >> unit_;
```

Handles the units without separate expression branches:

```
unit_.add("days",    ConditionTree::Limit::days)
         ("hours",   ConditionTree::Limit::hours)
         ("minutes", ConditionTree::Limit::minutes);
```

Because, now, the grammar just parses a `Limit` object you can do the evaluation *atomically* after the parse:

```
ConditionTree::Limit limit;
if (phrase_parse(iter, end, parser, ascii::space, limit))
{
    AddLimit(oTree, limit);
}
```

Separating parsing from evaluation enables you to add things like

- repeated evaluation of the same expression (without repeated parsing)
- simplifying the expression tree before evaluation
- validating before evaluation
- debugging
- slightly more interestingly, allows you to write `ApplyLimit` in a functional style, not mutating an object:

  ```
  ConditionTree ApplyLimit(ConditionTree const& ct, Limit limit) { 
      return ct + limit; // do something here
  }
  ```
- but most importantly: it hugely simplifies the grammar and saves you hours of your life that were better spent otherwise

See this **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2611af05c9fb98d4)**, outputting:

```
void AddLimit(ConditionTree&, ConditionTree::Limit): 5 minutes
```

### Listing

```
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/struct.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

namespace qi    = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace ascii = boost::spirit::ascii;

struct ConditionTree {
    struct Limit {
        unsigned value;
        enum unit_t { days, hours, minutes } unit;
    };

    friend void AddLimit(ConditionTree& ct, Limit limit) {
        std::cout << "AddLimit: " << limit.value;
        switch (limit.unit) {
            case Limit::days:    std::cout << " days\n"; break;
            case Limit::hours:   std::cout << " hours\n"; break;
            case Limit::minutes: std::cout << " minutes\n"; break;
        }
    }
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(ConditionTree::Limit, (unsigned,value)(ConditionTree::Limit::unit_t,unit))

template <typename Iterator = std::string::const_iterator, typename Skipper = ascii::space_type>
struct Parser: qi::grammar<Iterator, ConditionTree::Limit(), ascii::space_type>
{
    public:
        Parser() : Parser::base_type(limit_expression)
    {
        unit_.add("days", ConditionTree::Limit::days)
                 ("hours", ConditionTree::Limit::hours)
                 ("minutes", ConditionTree::Limit::minutes);

        limit_expression = "limit" >> qi::uint_ >> unit_;
    }

    qi::symbols<char, ConditionTree::Limit::unit_t> unit_;
    qi::rule<Iterator, ConditionTree::Limit(), Skipper> limit_expression;
};

int main()
{
    ConditionTree oTree;

    Parser<> parser;

    std::string strTest("limit5minutes");

    std::string::const_iterator iter(strTest.begin()), end(strTest.end());

    ConditionTree::Limit limit;
    if (phrase_parse(iter, end, parser, ascii::space, limit))
    {
        AddLimit(oTree, limit);
    }
}
```

Comment: @cv_and_he Thanks for noticing the edit, that's already worth the while :)