# Copying an object with a reference or pointer to another object

Tags: c++, reference, smart-pointers

I am designing a game where I need to copy certain components.

Here is what I need:

```
class Common { };

class Component
{
private:

    Common &_commRef;

public:
    
    Component(Common &commRef) :_commRef{ commRef }{}
};

int main()
{
    Common common;
    Component componentA(common);
    Component componentB(common);
    Component compCopy(common);
    
    compCopy = componentA; //can't do this
    
    return 0;
}
```

However, since references cannot be re-seated, I cannot copy `componentA` to `compCopy`.  This question was asked here : [Copying a C++ class with a member variable of reference type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841299/), but my question is about the answers themselves.

So, possible solutions are:

**Pass a raw pointer to the constructor of `Component` instead of a reference**:

```
class Common { };

class Component
{
private:

    Common *_commPtr;

public:
    
    Component(Common *commPtr) :_commPtr{ commPtr }{}
};

int main()
{
    Common common;
    Component componentA(&common);
    Component componentB(&common);
    Component compCopy(&common);
    
    compCopy = componentA; 
    
    return 0;
}
```

I am not sure if this is a good idea, because the class `Component` can now do strange things like calling `delete` on `commPtr`.

**Pass a smart pointer**:

```
class Common { };

class Component
{
private:

    std::shared_ptr<Common> _commPtr;

public:
    
    Component(std::shared_ptr<Common> commPtr) :_commPtr{ commPtr }{}
};

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<Common> commPtr = std::make_shared<Common>();
    Component componentA(commPtr);
    Component componentB(commPtr);
    Component compCopy(commPtr);

    compCopy = componentA; 
    
    return 0;
}
```

With this approach, we do not have the problem in the first method, but I am creating a `Common` object on the heap unnecessarily, as opposed to the first approach where we create it on the stack. My understanding is use the stack unless we are creating large objects (create objects with `new` is often misused/overdone?).

**Using a reference wrapper (as in the linked answer)**:

```
class Common { };

class Component
{
private:

    std::reference_wrapper<Common> _commRef;

public:
    
    Component(Common &commRef):_commRef{commRef}
    {}
};

int main()
{
    
    Common common;
    Component componentA(common);
    Component componentB(common);
    Component compCopy(common);

    compCopy = componentA; 
    
    return 0;
}
```

Which one should I prefer? Or, is there an alternate approach?

Using a reference wrapper looks the cleanest. Is there a downside to it?

Comment: I'd say (1) + copy/move constructors because of a least surprise principle. You can't copy a reference so any attempt to simulate that would be ambiguous.

Comment: @Osyotr Yes, I agree. However I have situations where I think I need copies (I might be wrong here) For example when running tests/simulations (Component represts a game board in a board game) ,  I have to tests moves and then reset the board. I could create a reset method instead of copy, but i was looking for a quick dirty way :)

Comment: @torres then I would say stick with `shared_ptr` so it can handle the common case while still being able to refer to new copies as needed.

Comment: @RemyLebeau OK that makes sense, and also it , I believe, will have the most predictable behavior. Thanks!

Comment: "... because the class Component can now do strange things like calling delete on commPtr". You might be surprised to learn that this can be done with references too: taking the address of the reference object and calling `delete` on it. It is deep, dark, secret only known to a select few bearded C++ gurus: a reference is really a pointer and the only difference is that `*` is automatically used with a reference variable, every time it's used. Abracadabra: the pointer is now a reference. The fact that a reference cannot be reseated is solely because of that.